# cannot find protocol declaration, but i'm actually importing it

Tags: objective-c, ios

I get an error: cannot find protocol declaration for 'SentencesDelegate'.
However I'm importing the header where the protocol is defined.
These are the 2 headers files (defining and using the protocol respectively):

SentencesViewController.h

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import "SansnuageAppDelegate.h"

// Define a new protocol
// Best practice - make this protocol conform to the <NSObject> protocol
@protocol SentencesDelegate <NSObject>

// By default, methods are "required"; you can change this by prefacing methods with "@optional"
- (void) setSentence:(NSString *)sentence;

@end

@interface SentencesViewController : UITableViewController
{
    SansnuageAppDelegate* appDelegate;
    NSArray *sentencesList;
}

@property (nonatomic, assign) id <SentencesDelegate> delegate;

@end
```

ComposerViewController.h

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import "SentencesViewController.h"
#import "ANColorPicker.h"
#import "SansnuageAppDelegate.h"

@interface ComposerViewController : UIViewController <SentencesDelegate, ANColorPickerDelegate, UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource>
{
    ANColorPicker * picker;
    UIView * colorView;
    UITableView * composerTableView;

    NSMutableArray *dataList;
    SansnuageAppDelegate* appDelegate; 

}

@property(nonatomic, retain) UIView * colorView;
@property(nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UITableView *composerTableView;
@property(nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UIButton *previewB;
@property(nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UIButton *sendB;

@end
```

thanks

Comment: Did you really mean `#import SansnuageAppDelegate;` in the second line of your first code block?

Comment: @Yuji uhm, yeah I really meant it, I need the delegate to get the managedObjectContext

Comment: There are no quotes or braces around the second import statement in 
SentencesViewController.h - Is that a typo or is that really how you have it?

Comment: @onnoweb No sorry, my fault, it was a typo. I haven't solved yet.

Comment: Is that ";" there - and not a typo - in '#import "SansnuageAppDelegate.h";'?

Comment: @onnoweb ok, now that damned line should be fine. I've just made typos to write it here, sorry.

Comment: Ironically, if I remove <SentencesDelegate>, in the implementation file, when I use "self.delegate" I get: Class 'ComposerViewController' does not implement the 'SentencesDelegate' protocol

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, so the solution was that I was importing #import "SentencesViewController.h"
 in the implementation file as well. Very stupid mistake, but the error description didn't help at all.